# When in snippet mode in VS Code, how can I ONLY move through placeholders using the Tab key without accepting suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

Assume I have this sample snippet

```
  "Sample HTML A snippet": {
    "prefix": "htmla",
    "body": [
      "<a href=\"${1:urlhere}\">${2:Text To Appear}</a>"
    ],
    "description": "Sample HTML A snippet"
  },
```

When I type "htmla" it is launched

If I happen to type "htmla" again because I want that exact text, and then hit the {Tab} key, I get a snippet within a snippet.

The only way to avoid that is to watch closely if the words I type produce a snippet suggestion and hit {ESC} key to close it.

How to directly move between placeholders using {Tab} key without having the need for that extra step.

i.e. prevent snippet within a snippet?

This is what happens when you type a serious of "htmla{tab}" key

```
<a href="<a href="<a href="<a href="urlhere">Text To Appear</a>">Text To Appear</a>">Text To Appear</a>">Text To Appear</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that you're getting quick suggestions while in snippet-mode already, you can take a workaround to just close the suggestions widget opened by the quick-suggestions feature, which you can do by pressing <kbd>escape</kbd>. Not ideal, but it'll get you by. Technically, this implies the "give up" solution of just disabling quick-suggestions (see the `editor.quickSuggestions` setting), but I'll assume that you don't want to do that.

I can reproduce this behaviour, and it's funny, because at least for the specific case you showed of accepting a snippet suggestion while in snippet mode, from the way that the default `{ "key": "tab", "command": "insertSnippet", "when": "editorTextFocus && hasSnippetCompletions && !editorTabMovesFocus && !inSnippetMode" },` keybinding is defined, it seems to me like VS Code wants the behaviour you want to be the case. But when I troubleshoot keybindings using the `Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette), I see that it's actually matching the `acceptSelectedSuggestion, when: suggestWidgetHasFocusedSuggestion && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus, source: built-in.` keyboard shortcut.

I suppose you could try to unbind that command and then define a modified version of it where the when clause includes `&& !inSnippetMode`, which would be like this, which you would put into your keybindings.json file (which you can open using the `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` command in the command palette):

```json
{ "key": "tab", "command": "-acceptSelectedSuggestion", "when": "suggestWidgetHasFocusedSuggestion && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus" },
{ "key": "tab", "command": "acceptSelectedSuggestion", "when": "suggestWidgetHasFocusedSuggestion && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus && !inSnippetMode" },
```

I gave that a spin and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much it works wonders, I would add step by step instructions now on how to achieve the desired result especially for newbies.

1. Press Ctrl+Shift+P to Open the Command Palette
2. Type "Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)
3. Search for this specific string "acceptSelectedSuggestion"
4. On the "when" : item, add behind string ""suggestWidgetHasFocusedSuggestion && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus" the string " && !inSnippetMode"
5. It should look like this

```
    {
        "key": "tab",
        "command": "acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "suggestWidgetHasFocusedSuggestion && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus &&!inSnippetMode"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily solved by enabling this setting:

```
Editor > Suggest: Snippets Prevent Quick Suggestions   // default is disabled
```

[image: snippets prevent suggestions setting]